# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x9)

Tags: c++, xcode, linked-list

I am trying to refreshen up on linked lists for class but i came across this error on the line where i set my condition for the `while` loop.

```
using namespace std;

class linkedList{
private:
    struct list{
        int num;
        list* next;
    };
    
    list* head;
public:
    
    void newList(int num);
    void display() const;
    
};

int main(){
    
    linkedList mylist;
    
    mylist.newList(5);
    mylist.display();
    
    return 0;
    
}

void linkedList::display() const{
    list* ptr;
    
    ptr = head;
    
    while (!ptr) {
        cout << ptr->num << endl;
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    
}

void linkedList::newList(int num){
    
    list* newNode;
    list* nodeptr = nullptr;
    
    newNode = new list;
    newNode->num = num;
    newNode->next = nullptr;
    
    if(!head){
        head = newNode;
    }else{
        nodeptr = head;
        
        while(nodeptr->next){
            nodeptr = nodeptr->next;
        }
    }
    
    nodeptr->next = newNode;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Three issues to correct:

1. Initialise `head` in your class definition:

   ```
   list* head = nullptr;
   ```
2. Indeed, there is an issue in the `while` statement. You'll want to *exit* the loop when the pointer is null (`!ptr`). To keep iterating, your condition is opposite, and that is what you must specify:

   ```
   while (ptr) {
   ```
3. In the `newList` method, the last statement is also executed when the condition in the preceding `if` was true. And in that case `nodeptr` is a null pointer... giving a null pointer exception (segmentation fault) in that last statement. So move that statement in the `else` block:

   ```
   }else{
       // ....
       nodeptr->next = newNode; // moved here
   }
   ```